# Variable not being assigned correctly

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script attached to the submission of a google form that posts to a Discord webhook containing the fields. However, about 4-5 days ago, my "options" variable fails to assign and returns "undefined"

I'm at a loss of what left to try. I can't tell if it's an issue with the rest of the script or google app scripts itself.

[image: Debug output]

Comment: Where in your code did you set the debug breakpoint? If it's above the line where the options variable is assigned it will be 'undefined'. What does the fetch call return? (status code, response). Also, try using Logger.log(options) and check if it returns anything

Comment: I don't know how, but upon using `Logger.log(options)` it started working.The fetch call was previously returning 400 because the message was empty, because options was essentiall null/undefined.